# What are RES interrupts (from Munin)

Tags: ubuntu, munin, interrupts

Our server recently had a very bad day, and one of the indicators/reasons seems to be that RES interrupts are douple their normal value, but what does this mean ?

(other interrupts: LOC+100%, eth1/TLB +30%)

Answer (score 0):

They are "Rescheduling interrupts", as far as I can tell they're caused when the kernel moves a process between CPUs to balance the load.

I'm not sure what it means.